# React/Redux and Firebase Realtime Database - Convert all timestamps in the store upon load/update, given a known offset

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, timezone

I have a React/Redux application.

I am fetching a set of "notes" from a Firebase Realtime Database. The "notes" has a Unix epoch timestamp "timestamp" stored in UTC time zone. I want the user to see all times in local time zone.
Upon fetch I need to adjust the "timestamp" to reflect the users time zone.

I am creating db subscriptions to update notes in the store.

What would the best approach to adjust the UTC timezone to the users local time?
I guess I first need to fetch the users settings and then adjust the "timestamp" on the fly?

My notes object

```
{
  title: "now",
  timestamp: "161651792000"
}
```

My user object

```
{
  displayName: "Mickey",
  userTz: "Europe\Stockholm",
  "userGmtOffset":3600"
}
```

Db subscription code

```
database.ref(`${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`).on('value', (myNoteAccessSnaps) => {
  ...
}
```

Many thanks! /K

Comment: Is your question [How to convert a UTC timestamp to the user's local timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+How+to+convert+a+UTC+timestamp+to+the+user%27s+local+timezone)?

Comment: Hi Frank! Thank you for the prompt reply! :D No, my question was rather along the lines of "How can I convert all timestamps in the store upon load/update, given a known offset" The links were useful though, even if they did not answer my question (^__^) /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezones only play a roll in how the date is displayed to a user.
If a date object is constructed using a timestamp created by Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, it will automatically have the same timezone as the local time zone. Just in case: [firebase. firestore. Timestamp.toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate)

On the other hand `getTimezoneOffset()` can be used to get the client's time zone. Check [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) and help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript) in case you want to make any research.

Comment: Hi rustyBucketBay! I am using Cloud functions and trigger .onCreate(). The timestamp os fetched by context.timestamp and converted to date object using new Date(context.timestamp). I cannot figure out how to get the UTC Unix Epoch time though. /K

Comment: So I am understanding that you are doing the new Date() from the timestamp in the server. That is the problem, right?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. A timestamp is an absolute point in time. .If you read a timestamp creating a new date, it will be in the client's local time. I guess that somewhere in your app you will read that timestamp from the database to display the date with a `toDate()` in the client, so the client will see that date according to his time zone from the absolute point in time the timestamp represents. Just as you demand in your question: `I want the user to see all times in local time zone. Upon fetch I need to adjust the "timestamp" to reflect the users time zone`

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I got a bit confused. I did not realise that Unix Epoch is ALWAYS in UTC. X-D Also, as you pointed out - creating a new date using a timestamp will reflect the users time zone. Understanding those concepts solved my issue!! Many thanks! /K